# Vaadin: resizing area is too big

Tags: css, vaadin

In the following picture it is clear: the resizing area overlaps with the arrows to sort the grid.
[image]

I tried a number of things: like setting a margin on the inputfield or a padding on the cell or add a style to the grid. In the browser, using the developer tools I can add padding to the header cells, but I cannot style the cells in java code, because vaadin doesn't have a getStyle() method.

The following code creates the grid:

```
processGrid = new Grid<>();
    new GridFactory<>(processGrid, this)
            .themeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES,
                    GridVariant.LUMO_WRAP_CELL_CONTENT,
                    GridVariant.LUMO_COLUMN_BORDERS)
            .height("calc(100vh - 295px)")
            .removeAllColumns()
            .widthFull();

    new GridColumnFactory<>(processGrid.addColumn(BusinessProcessDto::getSeqId), this)
            .width("10px")
            .header("ID")
            .sortable()
            .key("seqId").resizable();
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does indeed seem to be a bug in the Grid component. I've created a bug ticket about it: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/5637

In the meantime, you can override the resize handle's width with css e.g. like this:

```
vaadin-grid::part(resize-handle)::before {
  width: var(--lumo-size-m);
}
```

(I think --lumo-size-m is suitable as it's just small enough not to overlap the sorter, but still big enough to be easy to hit.)

Comment: I added it to my css, but it doesn't work

Comment: i changed the width to 2px and that's ok